# Import .pfx certificate into Azure KeyVault using C#: "certificate content can not be read"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I have been trying back and forth importing a certificate into Azure's KeyVault service with no success. The certificate has been correctly imported through Azure Portal successfully and I can even load it through X509Certificate2 and seems to work well.

Thing is that once I execute the `ImportCertificateAsync` method it throws an exception saying:

> The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content can not be read.
> Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12 format. Status: 400
> (Bad Request)

I'm actually loading the certificate from a local storage with a `File.ReadAllBytes`, creating an `ImportCertificateOptions` and calling `ImportCertificateAsync` method right away.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data, password);
if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
   return;

var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri("https://myenvironment-dev.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

var importOptions = new ImportCertificateOptions("importedFromCode", data);
var result = await client.ImportCertificateAsync(importOptions, cancellationToken);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me I wasn't actually [setting the certificate's password](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.importcertificateoptions.password?view=azure-dotnet#azure-security-keyvault-certificates-importcertificateoptions-password)!

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data, password);
if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
   return;

var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri("https://myenvironment-dev.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

var importOptions = new ImportCertificateOptions("importedFromCode", data) { Password = password };
var result = await client.ImportCertificateAsync(importOptions, cancellationToken);
```